# Tomcat 7 javax.el.ELException

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I restarted the httpd and tomcat service today, and after doing so. I was greeted with the following message.

I saw this thread http://www.coderanch.com/t/592922/Tomcat/enable-el-api-jar-ver

And did as they told. I checked, and the el-api.jar is there. I checked another server, and tomcat is running great with it as well.

The server is a Centos 6.4 (final) and Tomcat 7.0.23.

I tried everything, even replacing the jar files, but nothing seems to work.

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:189)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getExpressionFactory(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:108)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:189)
    javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getExpressionFactory(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:108)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.
```

Comment: What is the version of the el jar ?

Comment: It doesn't have a version. It's just el-api.jar. It's working on the other server with the same jar file.

Comment: Anyone has any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, make sure you have both these jars at `${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib`

```
el-api-2.2.jar // jar version could differ
el-impl-2.2.jar
```

Comment: I tried it, and it's giving me this error now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487048/java-lang-linkageerror-javax-servlet-jsp-jspapplicationcontext-getexpressionfac

Comment: Does, the accepted answer help? You need to verify that you don't have any server-provided jars in your application's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: No it doesn't. I made sure I removed the original el-api.jar. Still the same error is obtained. I think it's caused by the ep-api and el-imp conflicting with each other..

Comment: Where are you placing the jars. Within your app's lib folder or tomcat's lib directory?

Comment: The tomcat lib. I'm getting his error on the main page of tomcat. For example http://www.xxxxxx.com:8080

Comment: 19 before I replaced the el-api.jar. Now 20 with el-api-2.2.jar and el-impl-2.2.jar

Comment: Okay, I just checked my local Tomcat 7 install and it has 19 files with just el-api.jar. But, I don't use expressions on it and the el-api.jar certainly doesn't have the `com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` class. File size on `dir` is 46,084.

Comment: This is what's very weird. Another server also has 19 with the original el-api.jar and it's working fine.. :/

Comment: Okay, just checked the default install uses `org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` from `jasper-el.jar`. Can you check your `web.xml` is not overriding it?

Comment: Orverriding it how? The only mention of jasper is  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class> and no mention of expression. Or did you mean the catalina.properties?

Comment: I've seen context params pointing to com.sun.el.* class in certain JSF environments.

Comment: Why don't you do a find for all *el*.jar files under tomcat directory? something is definitely interfering.

Comment: I did try searching for it. I only got the ones I added. And I cannot see any reference to any el.* classes, apache or sun.

Comment: Ah, try replacing `jasper-el.jar` with `el-impl.jar`. There's no reason why two implementations would co-exist. This would explain the `LinkageError` as well.

Comment: It turned out one of the applications I had installed had a library that had el inside it. Which was weird considering I was opening the manager and not the app. I uninstalled it, restarted the tomcat and apache, and reinstalled it, and it seemed to have worked now.

Comment: @TedPat Hey, glad you got it working. I'm guessing you now have just the el-api.jar (with jasper-el.jar) in Tomcat just like the default install and that you reinstalled the other app with el.jar removed. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: thanks a lot,Ravi. my war was not working when i migrated to 7.0.47 from 6.0 and after adding these two jar it worked without touching the code. helped me and saved a lot of time.

Comment: @sana Glad to know the answer helped. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today on Tomcat 9.0.21

and as per this bug - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64097

It is a known bug with "el-api.jar" and has been fixed in following versions

Fixed in:

- master for 10.0.0.0-M1 onwards
- 9.0.x for 9.0.31 onwards
- 8.5.x for 8.5.51 onwards
- 7.0.x for 7.0.100 onwards

Solution :- You can upgrade tomcat to these versions or just bring over the "el-api.jar" from the lib folder of a newer tomcat (which has the fix), place it in your lib folder and restart tomcat.
It would work.