# Validation jsr 303 in JSP Page

Tags: java, spring, validation

I want to do validation jsr 303 in JSP page. When I fill correctly, everything works. When leaving an empty value, then error is output.

> Error is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.(InterpolationTerm.java:59)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:341)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:279)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.interpolate(LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.java:50)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:362)...

```
@Controller
public class ProductCreateController {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProductCreateController.class);

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;
@Autowired
private SaleService saleService;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createCourse(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("eMail", session.getAttribute("eMail"));
    if (session.getAttribute("name") == null) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("eMail", session.getAttribute("eMail"));

        User user = userService.findUserByName(session.getAttribute("name")
                .toString());


        CreateProductDTO createProductDTO = new CreateProductDTO();
        model.addAttribute(createProductDTO);


        return "create";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createCoursePost(Model model, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, @Valid CreateProductDTO createProductDTO,
        BindingResult result) {
    model.addAttribute("eMail", session.getAttribute("eMail"));

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        System.out.println("hasErrors");

        return "create";
    } else {

        model.addAttribute("eMail", session.getAttribute("eMail"));
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(createProductDTO.getName());
        product.setDescription(createProductDTO.getDescription());
        product.setLinks(createProductDTO.getLinks());
        product.setCategory(createProductDTO.getCategory());
        product.setCountry(createProductDTO.getCountry());
        product.setPrice(createProductDTO.getPrice());
        product = productService.createProduct(product);

        return "redirect:/products";
    }
   }

   }
```

**CreateProductDTO.java**

```
public class CreateProductDTO {
@NotEmpty  
private String name;
@NotEmpty  
private String category;
@NotEmpty  
private String description;
@NotEmpty  
private String links;
@NotEmpty  
private String country; 
@NotNull  
private int price;      

public CreateProductDTO() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**JSP page**

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
<style>
.error {
color: #ff0000;
}

.errorblock {
color: #000;
background-color: #ffEEEE;
border: 3px solid #ff0000;
padding: 8px;
margin: 16px;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>
      Create a new Product 
      <div class="logout">
        <span id="currentUserLogin">
          ${eMail}
        </span>
        <a href="logout.html">
          <i class="icon-off"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </h1>
  </header>
 <form:form    commandName ="createProductDTO"   method="POST">
  <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
   <fieldset>

      <div class="control-group">   
      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">  

            <form:input path="name" />
            <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="control-group">

      <label class="control-label">Category</label>
        <div class="controls">

        <form:input path="category" />
            <form:errors path="category" cssClass="error" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="controls">  
       <form:input path="description" />
            <form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />

        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Price</label>
        <div class="controls">  
        <form:input path="price" />
            <form:errors path="price" cssClass="error" />

        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="controls">  
         <form:input path="country" />
            <form:errors path="country" cssClass="error" />

        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Links</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <form:input path="links" />
            <form:errors path="links" cssClass="error" />

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <button id="createButton" name="createButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>

      </div>
    </fieldset>
 </form:form>
    <a class="btn" href="products.html">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**Messages**

> NotEmpty.createProductDTO.name = Name is required!
>
> NotEmpty.createProductDTO.category = Category is required!
>
> NotEmpty.createProductDTO.description = Description is required!
>
> NotEmpty.createProductDTO.links = Links is required!
>
> NotEmpty.createProductDTO.country = Country is required!
>
> NotNull.createProductDTO.price = Price is required!

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.nhl.web" />


<bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- bind your messages.properties -->
<bean  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
 </beans>
```

Comment: I think this question has been answered here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454672/spring-3-tomcat-6-form-validation-exception-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-j

Comment: I use <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: javax.el version 2.2