# failed to start my application in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

When I start the application in websphere 8.5.5 I got an error, and the application failed to start, 
I searched the log and got this stack trace . Do you guys have any idea ?

```
[8/21/14 17:58:57:437 EEST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@a0ccb3b2
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver&amp;#40&#59;Ljavax/el/ELResolver&amp;#59&#59;&amp;#41&#59;V
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver&amp;#40&#59;Ljavax/el/ELResolver&amp;#59&#59;&amp;#41&#59;V
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver&#40;Ljavax/el/ELResolver&#59;&#41;V
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1678)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:681)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:234)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [java.lang.LinkageError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487048/java-lang-linkageerror-javax-servlet-jsp-jspapplicationcontext-getexpressionfac). You probably have servlet/jsp related jars in your WEB-INF/lib. Try to remove them and test again.

Comment: but how can i know the jar causing the issue ?? As i have alot of jars in the application lib ?

Comment: For the beginning remove all jars that have packages javax.servlet.* , javax.el.* . You can add listing with jars to your question. This unfortunately happens, when you use maven and create bad pom files, not considering libs provided by Java EE server, not just plain web container like Tomcat.

Comment: I removed the el-api-2.2.jar from the shared library folder, and everything went fine,
seems there is a conflict between
"el-api-2.2.jar"  and "javax.j2ee.el.jar"
where "javax.j2ee.el" is application server jar.

Now everything is ok but I am afraid this may cause errors !

Thanks