# failed to start application due to jsp exception

Tags: jsp

When I start my application from my server, I got the error,which means there is a conflict between the server jars and the application jars, so is there away to know the jar name from the exception below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:681)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:234)
    ... 21 more
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the other libraries you have added in your classpath

Comment: Do you mean inside the lib folder ?

Comment: I've already told you to attach file list of libraries from WEB-INF/lib folder to your question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432259/failed-to-start-my-application-in-websphere-8-5-5. But instead you are posting same question again here, with even less information.

Comment: @gas, yes I know, but since I don't have the list right now (weekend), I thought those who are expert in jsp may know the issue from the stack trace.
Thanks

Comment: No problem. But for future it's better to edit question and add additional tag, rather than creating new one. It will be bounced automatically and showed in other searches.